# excuse me how to rename the slide master by pypptx or win32com

Tags: python, win32com, python-pptx

How to rename the slide master by pypptx or win32com?

I found the following code can read the name, but it can not rename.
Please tell me how I can do that?

```
# coding: utf8
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.oxml import parse_xml
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE

pptx = Presentation('./sw.pptx')
theme_part = pptx.part.part_related_by(RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.THEME)
pptx.rename_
print(theme_part.partname)
print(theme_part.blob)

xml_elements = parse_xml(theme_part.blob)
elements = xml_elements.xpath('/a:theme[@name]')
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.attrib.get('name'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SlideMaster` object has a read/write `.name` attribute:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('./sw.pptx')
slide_master = prs.slide_masters[0]
slide_master.name = "New Name"
```

Comment: thank you scaynny,but it does not work.from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('./sw.pptx')
slide_master = prs.slide_masters[0]
slide_master.name = "New Name"
# save a new pptx
prs.save('./sw2.pptx')

Comment: Maybe the question I asked is incorrect. My real idea is to modify the master theme, which is displayed in the bottom left corner of ppt.

Comment: @caedy please add a picture of the bottom-left corner on your screen. There's nothing that would answer to the description of a master theme name in that location on mine.

Comment: your are so nice.I want the effect just like the following image.I not allow to upload the image.  https://www.19moban.com/1.png

Comment: Did you try the above approach? From what I'm able to find on search, renaming the slide-master should do this. Make sure you save the presentation with `prs.save(...)` and reopen it. I'm unable to reproduce the problem as on the Mac it doesn't appear to show the theme name the same way.

Comment: I've tried,it can rename the master but it can't show on that way thanks a lot.